# node app fails to run on mojave: ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-gyp, macos-mojave

I've tried to unsuccessfully run a node app, which runs fine on both High Sierra and Windows 10, but fails on Mojave 10.14.1.
This is the error shown when running the gulp build_dev task:

```
[23:44:42] Requiring external module babel-register
fs.js:25
'use strict';
^

ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined
    at fs.js:25:1
    at req_ (/Users/user1/Documents/NodeProjects/myapp/node_modules/natives/index.js:137:5)
    at Object.req [as require] (/Users/user1/Documents/NodeProjects/myapp/node_modules/natives/index.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/Documents/NodeProjects/myapp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/user1/Documents/NodeProjects/myapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@1.0.0 dev: `node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build_dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user1/.npm/_logs/2018-11-04T22_44_42_709Z-debug.log
```

This is the content of the package.json file with all the dependencies used in the application:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test-dev": "node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js test_dev",
    "test-prod": "node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js test_prod",
    "dev": "node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build_dev",
    "prod": "node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build_prod"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "envify": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.1.6",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "multi-glob": "^1.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browserify": "^16.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sass-glob": "^1.0.8",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Any hint on how to debug this problem? Could be related to gcc compiler version?

node version: 11.1.0
npm version: 6.4.1

At this link I've uploaded the log of the "npm install" command to install dependencies: [npm_install.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hKiK2r0WvZEPuf5fWYgEMoJYwhANWRQ0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hmm, have you just recently upgraded your Node.js? Try deleting `node_modules` and installing them again from scratch.

Comment: Hi, that was already a clean install since I've cloned the app from the repo and tried to run on Mojave os

Comment: And all the other machines also have node 11.1?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try updating `natives` to the latest version. [This](https://github.com/addaleax/natives/commit/0abbec6b0e211c6bbe3bf0d2b33fcd68f5a6c980) commit seems to resolve the issue you're having.

Comment: Updated to version natives@1.1.6 and now it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I downgraded Node version from 10.15.0(LTS) to 10.10.0. And this fixed internalBinding error for me.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 10.10.0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, because it was not switching to the older version, but i was able to do the same thing with nvm and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was with the node_modules installation, so do the following.

- Perform a `yarn audit`
- Check if you have any critical vulnerabilities
- Either upgrade the version of the module or search for an alternative module.
- `yarn install`
- You should be good to go

Note: Issue was not with the node version in my case it was just a vulnerable module(gulp-angular-templatecache). I also suggest you do `npm upgrade` and `npm rebuild` if the above method doesn't work.

`npm audit` doesn't work with private repositories but `yarn audit` does.